# Plotting solution of an integral

Tags: plotting

I have used below code to plot the solution of an integral, but the code doesn't return anything. Could somebody please help me in this regard?

```
a=0.1;     
Assuming[
      t \[Element] Reals, 
     Plot[Integrate[-Sin[tp] Exp[-((
          16 a  Cos[tp - 2 t + 3 Pi/2] Cos[
            2 tp])/((1 - a^2) \[Pi]))], {tp, 0, 2 Pi}], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]]
```

Comment: did you check before plotting if the integrate actually works and it produces solution? it might be that Mathematica could not integrate it.

Comment: It doesn't work! @Nasser

Comment: Then this explains why the plot did not work.

Comment: But there might be a way to make it work @Nasser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate does not seem to be able to do it. Try `NIntegate`

```
ClearAll[t, tp, a];
a = 0.1;
tick = {Range[0, 2 Pi, Pi/2], Automatic};
foo[t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[-Sin[tp] Exp[-((16 a Cos[tp - 2 t + 3 Pi/2] 
      Cos[2 tp])/((1 - a^2) Pi))], {tp, 0, 2 Pi}]

Plot[foo[t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, Ticks -> tick, GridLines -> tick, 
 GridLinesStyle -> LightGray, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: what is foo[t_?NumericQ]?

Comment: @Marco just function name. change it to something else you prefer.

Comment: Is it possible to plot a density plot with variables $a$ and $t$?

Comment: @Marco it is probably possible. Please post separate question and and make it clear what is it you are asking for, someone should be able to help.

Comment: why is the argument of the function like this?  t_?NumericQ

Comment: @Marco `?NumericQ` just says that you are expecting the argument to be numeric when this function is called. That is all.

Comment: @Marco ,f[x_?NumericQ]=x^2 ;f[5] give 25, f[x] give f[x] ,but f[x_]=x^2;f[x] give x^2,which is useful to hold the form.